# uploading sketch using mcp2221 to Atmel Mega1284P

Tags: usb, uart, microchip

Hi I am unable to upload sketch to Atmel mega1284p using a mcp2221 usb to uart converter IC.

I have a simple code prints "message received" It works to program the Mega1284p using arduino nano as ISP. But not using the MCP2221 over usb.  I took a long time and eventually errors out. I tried pressing reset button on ATMega while uploading, I tried swapping TX and RX. I double checked COM port. Please help.

avrdude:

```
     System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\hhuynh\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\MightyCore\hardware\avr\2.0.1/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM5
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 38400
```

An error occurred while uploading the sketch

[image: This is my setting]

[image: This is similar to how my circuit is connected]

This is my setup.

This schematic is simular to how mine is setup.

Comment: Are you going to tell us the error you received??

Comment: avrdude:

     System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\hhuynh\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\MightyCore\hardware\avr\2.0.1/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM5
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 38400
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

Answer (score 1):

Turns out bootloader is erased when programming using arduino as ISP. I need to re flash the bootloader and program through the MCP2221.

Comment: Yes, good realization.  There's probably already the equivalent question here with the same answer but figuring it out for yourself is commendable.   Incidentally, this is unavoidable - the ATmega series can only do a partial erase (preserving the bootloader) when manipulating the flash from an internal program. The only erase operation available via ISP is a full-chip erase, so using ISP to replace a program *always* and *unavoidably* wipes out the bootloader on these. It is however possible to use ISP to load both a program and a bootloader, either in one operation or without a second erase.